# Is there a Ruby way to sort an array of strings by number of words?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby array of strings:

```
array = ["dog eats", "dog", "cat eats dog"]
```

I want to sort this array by the number of words (or tokens) in the string, in decreasing order like so: (3 words, 2 words, 1 word):

```
sorted = ["cat eats dog", "dog eats", "dog"]
```

How can I do this in Ruby? I can think of a brute-force method but was wondering if there was a Ruby-like way to do this in 1 line or even just a few.

Comment: When you ask for code, you need to show where you've searched, and why that didn't help. You say "I can think of a brute-force method" but don't show us you tried anything. In the future, please show what you've tried. Remember, you're asking us to help you, so show you're also helping yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Array#sort` and `split`, like so:

```
array = ["dog eats", "dog", "cat eats dog"]
 => ["dog eats", "dog", "cat eats dog"]
array.sort { |a,b| a.split.length <=> b.split.length }
 => ["dog", "dog eats", "cat eats dog"]
```

That sorts in ascending number of whitespace-separated words.

**Edit**: per @MarkReed, to reverse, reverse the order of the sort expression:

```
array.sort { |a,b| b.split.length <=> a.split.length }
 => ["cat eats dog", "dog eats", "dog"]
```

You could `split` on any other separator if desired.

Comment: I didn't downvote u. I'm actually using your answer and marked it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks. I have to say that @michas has a more-elegant solution in this case, though. Throw in the `.reverse` and it does the same exact thing, just more succinctly.

Comment: `sort` will be slower than `sort_by`. For every comparison `sort` requires two splits of the string, and the calculation of the length, one for each element, the first time the element is seen. `sort_by` will remember the calculations and only do them once per element. ANYTIME there is a comparision of two elements that are not simple objects, you should consider using `sort_by`.

Comment: If you're going to use `sort` with an explicit block, you should take advantage of that and just swap the order of `a` and `b` in the comparison, rather than calling `.reverse` on the result of the whole thing.

Answer (score 8):

The array class provides a `sort_by` method. Just split the sting and count the components:

```
array.sort_by{|x| x.split.count}
```

Comment: Since OP wants decreasing order, you should put a minus sign in front of the `x.split.count`.

Comment: Or call `reverse` on the result.